# how to restore a file saved in the .tmp folder of ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, file-recovery, temporary-files

One of my friends was working on a 10 page college paper, and saved it in the tmp folder of ubuntu. The file is listed under LibreOffice Writer's "recent files" but when clicked on, it comes up with an error that says "this file does not exits." I am guessing that the problem is that all tmp files are deleted to save space, but I was wondering if there was a way to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Linux, you may be able to use testdisk, which comes bundled with photorec. I didn't think it would work, but it recovered my .odt document saved in the /tmp file.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
sudo photorec
```

(Then follow the prompts)

See original reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1352636